# Handle Request: ChoicesType

Tags: forms, sorting, symfony

So I have this `ChoiceType Form` that will sort the items:

```
$sort = $this->createForm(ChoiceType::class, NULL, array(
    'choices' => array(
        '...' => 'default',
        'A-Z' => 'title_up',
        'Z-A' => 'title_down',
        'Price low to high' => 'price_up',
        'Price high to low' => 'price_down',
    ),
));
```

I want to use the `Choices` so that when one of them is selected from the dropdown menu will do this: `$products = "SELECT a FROM AppBundle:Product a ORDER BY a.title ASC"`.

I tried this:

```
$sort->handleRequest($request);
if($sort->isSubmitted() && $sort->isValid()) {
    if (isset($default)) {
        $products = "SELECT a FROM AppBundle:Product a ORDER BY a.title ASC";
        return $this->render('AppBundle:main:index.html.twig', array('products' => $products, ));
    }
}
```

But `$default` is not working, since is not defined. I dont know how to access the `choices`, so I can pass them to an `if` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to write something like this:

```
$sort = $this->createFormBuilder()
    ->setAction($this->generateUrl('your_process_route_here'))
    ->setMethod('POST')
    ->add('select', ChoiceType::class, [
        'placeholder' => 'Please select',
        'choices' => [
            '...' => 'default',
            'A-Z' => 'title_up',
            'Z-A' => 'title_down',
            'Price low to high' => 'price_up',
            'Price high to low' => 'price_down',
        ]
    ])
```

To get the value inside the `<select>` element:

```
$select = $request->request->get('select'); // this will contain whatever value you've selected from the dropdown
```

Check if the value is what you expect, and then create the query:

```
if ('default' == $select){ // or you can use a switch
    // create a custom method inside your Repository class containing the SELECT, and call it here
}
```

That `select` from `->add('select', ...)` will be the name attribute for your `<select>` html element.